# What does "negation of enumeration" mean?

Tags: c++, enums

I was reading some code and I came across: `static_cast<uint32_t>(!value);` where value is a following enum:

```
typedef enum PValue {
    Lo = 0b0,
    Hi
} PValue;
```

What's the result of `!value` when `value = Lo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Plain old" enumerations (that is, those declared by means of `enum` and not `enum class`) have an underlying integral type. From the standard:

> The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can
>   represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. It is
>   implementation-defined which integral type is used as the underlying
>   type for an enumeration except that the underlying type shall not be
>   larger than int unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an
>   int or unsigned int. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying
>   type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0.

That is, `enum`s are basically tagged integers. You can convert any given `enum` type to an `int` and back, even under implicit casting. Since `operator!()` is not defined for `enum` types, an expression of the form `!a`, where `a` is of an `enum` type, is equivalent to `!static_cast<int>( a )`. This means that the usual rules for `operator!()` on integral types apply:

```
 ______ ______
|      |      |
|   a  |  !a  |
|______|______|
|      |      |
| ==0  |   1  |
|______|______|
|      |      |
| !=0  |   0  |
|______|______|
```

Now, in your particular example:

```
typedef enum PValue {
    Lo = 0b0,
    Hi
} PValue;
```

`Lo`s integral representation is `0`, which would be even if you didn't specify it explicitly. `Hi`s integral representation, since not explicity set, is `Lo`'s plus one, that is, `1`.

Thus, `!Lo == !0 == 1 == Hi` and `!Hi == !1 == 0 == Lo`.

Answer (score 2):

The backing integer value of `Lo` is `0` and `1` for `Hi`. Note, that `!0 == 1` in C and `!a == 0` for any non-zero value `a`. Thus, this static cast would evaluate to unsigned `1`.

Comment: so !0 for any integer type evaluate to 1?

Comment: @Quest yes, it is mentioned somewhere in the standard